# ASP.NET Core Site Deployement

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I am deploying my asp.net core site on Local IIS and binding is 
`http//localhsot:{portnumber}` but the website is not running and giving me error

```
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
```

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module             IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler            Not yet determined
Error Code         0x8007007b
Requested URL      http://localhost:9001/
Physical Path      D:\Deploy\Stagging - Copy
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User         Anonymous
```

But when my binding is 
`https//localhsot:{portnumber}`
web site runs fine
why this is happening I don't want to run the site on Https

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and paste it as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is already a binding rule binding your localhost domain name and HTTP protocol.

If you just installed the IIS service and it will create a default site automaticly and bind your 80 port.

Try removing the default website and try again.

And try not set the HTTP host name of your binding and just leave it empty. When you leave the host name empty it will bind all incomming requests from the port.

The difference between IIS http binding and https binding is that HTTP binding is based on the `host` header in the HTTP request and the https binding is based on SNI. Now your https binding is working fine so it is possible that your HOST name settings caused this issue.